# Converting Canvas to OpenGL Android Game

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I started my first game 6 months ago and everything was fine and dandy. Now I've started added  a lot of details into the game with some problems.

Problems.
1. Out of memory on older devices (Android 2.3) with high res screen. VM memory is only small on these. Don't have this problem with newer devices.

1. Getting a little lag which is bad on the super high-res devices.
2. Drawing large bitmaps is slow.

Currently I have:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, Pos.x, Pos.y, null);
```

Is there an easy way of converting this to OpenGL, as I now have hundreds of bitmaps using the above.

Ie.

```
GLView.drawBitmap(mBitmap, Pos.x, Pos.y, null);
```

Can anyone recommend something, I'm fairly new to OpenGL.

Answer (score 0):

I have working on a large project which requires to support low performance devices for nearly a month. For your problem, I have few suggestions:

1. Consider whether you use jpg, png and bmp. According to my experience, jpg can improve the performance of old devices. However, there is a huge issue with jpg: it does not support transparency image. Think about it.
2. By using png (in case you wanna use it), try with 8 bit img. It will reduce the quality of the image a little bit. I mean, you can not easily recognise it, but it definitely improve lots of performance.
3. A tip is that, you can reload and draw all the images before starting the app. I do not have a chance to look at your code, but when I did it, my app changes from 35 fps to 55-60 fps.
4. Using sprite instead of titled background. Also, only use title where it is absolutely necessary.

Cheers.